# Java Card Eclipse Plug-in: APDU I/O API is hanging on powerUp()

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu, jcop

My development environment:

1. I downloaded an example for APDU I/O API: https://github.com/RimGazzeh/JavaCard_Wallet.git
2. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
   Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
   Build id: 20230907-1323
   OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
   Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
   Java runtime version: 17.0.8.1+1
   Java version: 17.0.8.1
3. Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0
4. Java Card Development Kit Tools 3.1.0

This is the issue that I have:

If I check "Do not open APDU console"
[image]
then I get the error message

> Exception in thread "main" 0xffffff82     at
> com.sun.javacard.apduio.ClientT1Protocol.exchangeApdu(ClientT1Protocol.java:55)
> at
> com.sun.javacard.apduio.CadT1Client.exchangeApdu(CadT1Client.java:33)
> at monpackageclient.MyClient.Select(MyClient.java:61)   at
> monpackageclient.RunClient.main(RunClient.java:17)

If I uncheck "Do not open APDU console" then the Client is hanging on powerUp().

I started in both scenarios the Eclipse Simulator manually. But in the second scenario I also run the scripts: cap-monpackage.script (I commented the line //powerdown; out) and afterwards the script create-monpackage.monpackage.MyServer.script.